# auto refresh on wicket page

Tags: wicket

I have scenario  to auto refresh the wicket page but it is base page and all pages are extending it .I dont want refresh all extending pages only base page.

right now I am using html meta tag.It is refreshing all the pages.Is it possible to refresh only base page

Answer (score 5):

When you have a

```
public class BasePage extends Page
```

and then another

```
public class SubPage extends BasePage
```

you don't actually get them as separate pieces.  This method of class (and markup) extending only exists to make the process more "object" and "java" like.  In the end, the entire page hierarchy is combined together to a single, rendered page.

Now, if you want one sub-part of the page to refresh, I suggest creating a `Panel` and adding an `AjaxSelfUpdatingTimerBehavior` to that component.  This will let you auto refresh any part (or multiple parts) of a page without the entire thing re-rendering.

Comment: I have added AjaxSelfUpdatingTimerBehavior on listview  but is not working and adding listview in panel because I have to check for the page status.

Comment: `ListViews` are one of the few components that cannot be updated via Ajax.  Instead, put a standard `WebMarkupContainer` around the `ListView` and attach the behavior to that instead.  Also, it would be helpful to see some code.  It very well may be that the update IS happening, but you're failing to change the data elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

First off I agree with @jbrookovers suggestion.

However, If you do actually want the hole page to refresh, Why not create a new class `RefreshingBasePage`? Then just move your `<meta refresh....>` to the new classes .html file. Just insert the refresh into the head via a `<wicket:head></wicket:head>` element.

Then you can leave your other pages free to inherit from `BasePage` without the refresh getting in the way.